# refresh posts in blogengine.net

Tags: caching, blogengine.net

I have installed blogengine.net on a windows azure website. When I post new blogitem it takes a long time (couple of hours) until the post is displayed on the website. Is it possible to display blogs immediately?

Answer (score 0):

If your server is in a different Time Zone than you are writing from you have to configure the 
Server Time Offset.  In the Admin Interface, under settings, on the basic tab you should see the following fields on the left hand side of the screen.

[image: Server Time Offset Example]

Calculate the offset between where you are and the datacenter your site is hosted in and put the positive or negative number here.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version of BlogEngine.Net

This issue is much easier to set.

You just set the time zone in which your server is located in.

https://github.com/rxtur/BlogEngine.NET

[image: Time Zone Setting]